# Can not align text undeneath overlapping images

Tags: html, image, css, css-float

I am trying to get text to display under my overlapping images.  I have two images side by side which are to be voted on so the "VS" image overlaps the other two images in the middle which works perfectly.  When I try to get text to display under each image to be voted on, however, it seems to display towards the top behind the images, not underneath as it would normally.

Here's a codepen of what it does at the moment:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdemaz

```
html:

 ​<div align="center">
 <div id="vs">
 <a href=""><img id="png1" src="/puppies/8.jpg" /></a><p
 class="left">username<br>Description<br>Puppies name</p>
 <img id="png2" src="/images/vs.png" /> 
 <a href=""><img id="png3"  src="/puppies/8.jpg" /></a><p
  class="right">username<br>Description<br>puppies name</p>
 </div>
 </div>

 css:

​#png1 {
position:absolute;
top:30px;
left:0;
z-index:0;
}

#png2 {
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:260px;
z-index:1;
}
#png3 {
position:absolute;
top:30px;
left:315px;
z-index:0;
}
#vs{
position: relative;
width: 620px;
height: 310px;
}
p.left{
 position:absolute;
top:315px;
left:0px;
z-index:4;
text-align:left;
}
p.right{
 position:absolute;
top:315px;
left:315px;
z-index:4;
text-align:left;

}
```

Comment: can you please create a fiddle, easier to debug!

Comment: @radiant do it by your own https://github.com/jsfiddle/stack-fiddle-chrome-extension

Comment: @tobaiasjl, sweet, thanks will check that out.

Comment: Please do not use the `align` and `valign` attributes, they are depreciated.

Comment: thanks guys, upload a codepen of what I currently have, the 1st reply below does put the text exactly where I want it but the VS no longer overlaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you're looking to do. You're setup isn't the best. I reworked the HTML/CSS, is this what you want:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJMeGr

```
a{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relatve;
  z-index: 9;
}
img{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.left{
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.right{
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#vs{
  text-align: center;
}
.vs{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

<div>
  <div id="vs">
    <a class="left" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" />
      <br>puppies name
      <br>username
      <br>Description
    </a>

    <img class="vs" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />

    <a class="right" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" />
      <br>puppies name
      <br>username
      <br>Description
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @hungerstar, added it.

Comment: Well spotted. I didn't add this by the way (part of the original markup)

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for all ihelp, Paul ... the codepen above has the text exactly how I wanted it but the VS image I being displayed between the image as opposed to overlapping the left and right image. ie there should be like a 8px spacing between the images and the VS should be in the center overlapping the images.

Comment: @PaulRedmond yes I noticed and added a comment to the question also about depreciated markup. Thanks for doing all the updates! I'll remove my comments shortly!

Comment: @user3696845 You could use negative margins and `position` with `z-index` to do that. I updated it, does that work for you?

Comment: @PaulRedmond That's awesome, Works great for me on its own but when I put it in my style sheet it breaks and I can seem to find why.Is there any way to make the css unique, ie a and img? not sure if that's the problem but ive tried many things with no joy. thank you.

Comment: Sure, use specific class names for each of these elements. Without seeing your other style sheet, I can't say for sure where the conflicts are. Can you mark as correct please since I solved the specific issue you were having?